# Change icon based on JSON attributes

Tags: json, icons, leaflet

Here's the map I'm working on:

http://members.upcpoczta.pl/w.racek/mapa.html

I would like to change icon that shows up in the right-top corner infobox (when selecting a route) accordingly to properties of JSON file (colour tag). There are 5 base colours used for marking bicycle routes (blue, red, green, yellow, black and no colour), almost all of them have colour (maybe 10% have symbol or different markings). I have 5 png icons which should be linked with this. At the moment I was able to put in simple html link and it only shows red icon but maybe there is a way to change it according to json properties?

Here is the part of the code that is responsible for displaying this infobox:
        var info = L.control();

```
    info.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    info.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML =   (props ?
            '<b>' + '<img src="img/red.png " height="42" width="42" >   ' + props.name
            : 'Kliknij na szlak');
    };

    info.addTo(map);
```

Right now icon is always red.

I will greatful for tips. Thanks!

Comment: how looks your json file?

Comment: Here is a part of it :      var rower = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"osm_id":"50272","name":"Euroroute R1 - part Poland","colour":"green","network":"icn","ref":"R1","descriptio":null,"length":null,"operator":null,"state":null,"website":null,"official_r":null,"old_ref":null,"distance":null},"geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[18.7691769,53.6058359],     ..... etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using is wrong to start with:

```
this._div.innerHTML =   (props ?
        '<b>' + '<img src="img/red.png " height="42" width="42" >   ' + props.name
        : 'Kliknij na szlak');
```

My guess is you are trying to use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Which doesn't work that way. For example when one would normally do this:

```
var value = 'foobar';
var result;

if (value === 'foobar') {
    result = true;
} else {
    result = false;
}
```

With a ternary you can write it shorthand like this:

```
var value = 'foobar';
var result = (value === 'foobar') ? true : false;
```

Or in this example when returning a boolean `true` or `false`, one could even do this (but thats way beyond the point here):

```
var value = 'foobar';
var result = (value === 'foobar');
```

Your syntax is way off or i'm not understanding what you're trying to do. Next for the string concatination you are doing:

```
'<b>' + '<img src="img/red.png " height="42" width="42" >   '
```

Can be simply written as:

```
'<b><img src="img/red.png " height="42" width="42" >   '
```

Now for the actual solution using ternary operator and concat:

```
this._div.innerHTML = (props) ?
        '<b><img src="img/' + props.color + '.png " height="42" width="42" >' + props.name + '</b>' :
        'Kliknij na szlak';
```

Doing it with a normal operator:

```
if (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<b><img src="img/' + props.color + '.png " height="42" width="42" >' + props.name + '</b>';
} else {
    this._div.innerHTML = 'Kliknij na szlak';
}
```

I'de suggest, using the latter if you're having trouble with this. It's easier to understand, so you're less likely to make mistakes.

Comment: That solved it. I deleted var color='red'; //default color
if(props.colour) 
    color=props.colour; and added just <img src="img/' + props.color + '.png " Thank you!

Comment: I refreshed my page, looking good! A little slowish on firefox though (weird because json file is only 1mb). Anyway fully working. I've added distance as well.

Answer (score 0):

I looked your source, proops got name and colour, so you can try this:

```
 info.update = function (props) {
var color='red'; //default color
if(props.colour) 
    color=props.colour;

    this._div.innerHTML =   (props ?
        '<b>' + '<img src="img/'+color+'red.png " height="42" width="42" >   ' + props.name
        : 'Kliknij na szlak');
};
```

Comment: That would end up loading something like `bluered.png` ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your try but it doesn't work. Infobox just dissapeared.

Comment: Still the same :( Infobox is not visible.